# Matrix sorting in C

Tags: c, sorting, matrix, columnsorting

I have a matrix like the below

```
Col1 Col2   Col3
5   10      3
2   4       0
7   14      0
2   6       1
1   2       1
4   8       2
6   12      3
```

I want to sort the matrix based in ascending order based on the Col2. The matrix should look like

```
Col1 Col2   Col3
1     2      1
2     4      0
2     6      1
4     8      2
5     10     3
6     12     3
7     14     0
```

I am unsure of how any methods available in C do perform this.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Read in each line of the file, parse the line to extract (at least) the Col2 value, record the data into a data structure with the Col2 value as the key, sort and output. That's the general algorithm. Try coding each step at a time. If you then have any specific difficulties then show your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: you could make a struct of 3 integers where each represents each column, populate that struct with your data then run some loops to sort the data then print the results onto the screen. Start with tutorials on the net and then share the code you tried so far so we can help better.

Comment: are you asking the logic of doing it or code itself?

Comment: I got the solution to my problem. I have used qsort method for sorting. I have used comparator to compare my values and sort by rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int(*comparer) (int a, int b);

int compareasc ( const void *pa, const void *pb ) {
    const int *a = *(const int **)pa;
    const int *b = *(const int **)pb;
    if(a[0] == b[0])
        return a[1] - b[1];
    else
        return a[0] - b[0];
}
int comparedsc ( const void *pa, const void *pb ) {
    const int *a = *(const int **)pa;
    const int *b = *(const int **)pb;
    if(a[2] == b[2])
        return b[1] - a[1];
    else
        return b[2] - a[2];
}

int main(void){
    int **array,**array2;
  //  int 8 = 10;
    //int i;
    int pid[8],priority[8],arrival[8];
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[255];
    fp = fopen("process.rtf","r");
    if(fp ==NULL)
      perror("File not found");
    else{
        int i =0;
        while(fgets(buff,100,fp)!=NULL){
          sscanf(buff,"%d  %d  %d",&pid[i],&arrival[i],&priority[i]);
          i++;
          }
        fclose(fp);
        }
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
      pid[i] = pid[i+1];
      priority[i]=priority[i+1];
      arrival[i] = arrival[i+1];
    }
    /*
    * Sorting the dataset in Ascending order based on the Arrival time
    */
    array = malloc(8 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        array[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        array[i][0] = pid[i];
        array[i][1] = arrival[i];
        array[i][2] = priority[i];
    }
    printf("The original dataset\n");
    for(int i = 0;i < 7;++i)
        printf("%2d %2d %2d\n", array[i][0], array[i][1],array[i][2]);

    printf("\n");

    printf("Dataset sorted based on the arrival in ascending order:\n");
    qsort(array, 8, sizeof array[2], compareasc);

    for(int i = 1;i < 8;++i)
        printf("%2d %2d %2d\n", array[i][0], array[i][1],array[i][2]);

      /*--------------------------------------------------*/
      /*
      * Sorting the dataset in Desceding order based on the priority
      */
      printf("\n");
      array2 = malloc(8 * sizeof(int*));
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
          array2[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
          array2[i][0] = pid[i];
          array2[i][1] = arrival[i];
          array2[i][2] = priority[i];
      }
      printf("Original Dataset:\n");
      for(int i = 0;i < 7;++i)
          printf("%2d %2d %2d\n", array2[i][0], array2[i][1],array2[i][2]);

      printf("\n");
      printf("Dataset sorted based on priority in descending order:\n");
      qsort(array2, 8, sizeof array2[2], comparedsc);

      for(int i = 1;i < 8;++i)
          printf("%2d %2d %2d\n", array2[i][0], array2[i][1],array2[i][2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is an arrayIndexOutOfBounds issue: array 'priority[8]' accessed at index 8 which is out of bounds
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
      pid[i] = pid[i+1];
      priority[i]=priority[i+1];
      arrival[i] = arrival[i+1];
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COL_SIZE 3

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
#if 0
    int (*x)[COL_SIZE] = (int(*)[COL_SIZE])a;
    int (*y)[COL_SIZE] = (int(*)[COL_SIZE])b;
    int col2_0 = x[0][1];
    int col2_1 = y[0][1];
#endif
    int col2_0 = ((int *)a)[1];
    int col2_1 = ((int *)b)[1];
    return (col2_0 > col2_1) - (col2_0 < col2_1);
}

int main(void) {
    int matrix[][COL_SIZE] = {
        {5, 10, 3},
        {2,  4, 0},
        {7, 14, 0},
        {2,  6, 1},
        {1,  2, 1},
        {4,  8, 2},
        {6, 12, 3}
    };
    size_t sizeof_row = sizeof(*matrix);
    size_t num_of_row = sizeof(matrix) / sizeof_row;

    qsort(matrix, num_of_row, sizeof_row, cmp);

    for(int r = 0; r < num_of_row; ++r){
        for(int c = 0; c < COL_SIZE; ++c){
            printf("%2d ", matrix[r][c]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```